# How to make a dynamic model's field value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How to make a models which the field's value is automatically set from another models's field?

Example:

1st model

```
class PurchasingDetail(models.Model):
    ....
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.1'))], help_text="kilogram")
    ....
```

2nd model

```
class Warehouse(models.Model):
    ....
    total_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    ....
```

What I want is on the `Warehouse.total_weight` is always set `sum` of all `weight` on `PurchasingDetail`. So, if I insert a new data on `PurchasingDetail`, the `Warehouse` updated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make total_weight a property that calls a queryset and then return the sum, there isn't any need to save it to the database.

```
@property
def total_weight(self):
    return queryset_with_sum_annotation.values('sum_value').sum_value
```